# Error with transaction on the blockchain

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, ringct, blockchain, cold-storage, transaction-data

Today I experienced the strangest error while sending moneros from one wallet to another. So thought I would share and see if anyone knows what was the cause or could shed anymore light on it.

Sent coins to one of my wallets, everything was fine 'money successfully sent' showed on the terminal window, after 20mins coins didn't show up on recipient wallet but showing as spent from the sender.

After copping the transation hash I managed to find the transaction as well as confirming which block it was in...... Using tx key and view key I double checked that I didn't send it to the wrong address.

89 Confirmations later coins still not showing up at all, and about 100 confirmations and hour or so later the coins showed up but from a different block than the hash id that was given in the original transaction.

Not sure if I am just being stupied or what, anyone here have any ideas what this could be? ringct perhaps?

Thanks guys. Peach

Comment: ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvG2U.png)![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V2KG.png)![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U813C.png)![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrLdD.png) Why????? I don’t understand..i want to Changelly in coinomi...Monero Changelly to digibyte..

Comment: Why error..i don’t understand that error code -30005

Answer (score 1):

Transactions IDs and block IDs are two different things, so it's not surprising that those are different.

Your transaction probably just took a lot of time to get added to a block. There's sometimes a glut of transactions waiting for inclusion, and the block size does not increase as readily as it should (which will be fixed soon), so that can mean some delay while the glut persists.

Comment: Can it be a blockchain reorganization ?

Comment: Yes, I think I might have misread: "from a different block than the hash id that was given in the original transaction." maybe the hash id refers to a block found in the txkey/viewkey check, in which case it's probably a reorg as you mentioned. Not clear without more precise wording in the question.

Comment: @MoroccanEngineer What caused a blockchain reorganization? just really interested to understand why it happened and what causes it.

Comment: @riifella IDK if it is what happened, just that it can happen. See http://monero.stackexchange.com/a/3313/110